# Run Eclipse Che 7 beta 4 in Kubernetes

Tags: eclipse-che

I have installed Che following [this](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-6/kubernetes-single-user.html) << Please provide a fully working description

But I am unable to make it work with domain, but is it not possible with port-forward?

Comment: Could you please try installing Che on kube via chectl - https://github.com/che-incubator/chectl ?

Comment: Yes, thanks - I will do that and get back to you

Comment: Looks like it is only for minikube?

Comment: But very nice ctl work!

Comment: hmm, I thought it is not only for local deployment and it should support deployment on any k8s cluster. Anyway, were you able to achieve what you wanted to locally via chectl?

Comment: I have a gke cluster that I am using, but I will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Please, find the updated installation guide with the various supported installation methods - https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/che-quick-starts/